# Javascript, remove jQuery call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `file.js` like this:

```
// TICautocapture.js

var TICautocapture = (function(){
  var lib = {...}
  var error_handler;
  var handleError = (error_code, error_callback) => {...}
  function autocapture(container, options){...}

  return autocapture;
})();

if(window.jQuery){
  (function($){
    $.fn.autocapture = function(options){
      TICautocapture(this.attr('id'), options);
    }
  }(jQuery));
}
```

My question is (I'm not sure how jQuery works at this)

- What is doing the last `if` statement?

My idea is to convert that all function in a React util like

```
const TICautocapture = () => {
  // all the code inside
}

export default TICautocapture;
```

And to use its methods and values, but I don't understand what it is doing that last part that I said. Any help please.

Comment: that if checks if you got jQuery imported and then makes a jQuery function / plugin from TICautocapture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is doing the last `if` statement?

It is simply checking if jQuery exists in the window object since the `$` alias is accessed in the following instruction. This is an example of [IFEE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). The code checks if `window.jQuery` exists, then passes it to the IFEE and catches it as `$` in the parameter for that function.

I hope this answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

`$.fn` is an alias for jQuery.prototype which allows you to extend jQuery with your own functions in your case its *autocapture*. And if statements just checking if JQuery is present or not for your page.